# Cannot find daemon after daemonizing python script

Tags: python, linux, daemon, kill, python-daemon

I daemonized a python script using the  daemonize python library, but now  I  cannot find the daemon  that it spawned. I want to find the daemon and  kill  it to make some changes  to the  script.

I used the following to daemonize:

> pidfile='/tmp/filename.pid'
>
> daemon = Daemonize(app='filename',pid=pidfile, action=main)
>
> print("daemon started")
>
> daemon.start()

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window and try the following:

`ps ax | grep <ScriptThatStartedTheDaemon>.py`

It should return the PID and the name of the process. Once you have the PID, do:

`kill <pid>`

Depending on how many times you've run your script, you may have multiple daemons running, in which case you'd want to kill all of them.

To make sure the process was terminated, run the first line of code again. The process with the PID that you killed shouldn't show up if it was successfully terminated.